# Changing line width of all lines in first row of table

Tags: tables

I am new to using LaTeX. I started to creating a simple table and found it difficult to create all lines in first row of table (horizontal and vertical) wider than the rest of table.
How can I do that?
Thanks, Thomas

Edit:
I try to edit code of what I have in mind, maybe it will be more specific.
Consider please this table:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | l | X[c] | l | }
\hline
item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
\hline
item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
```

And I want the first and second \hline and vertical line before "item11", all vertical lines between items11, 12 and 13 and vertical line after item 13 wider than the rest of lines in the table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried, and perhaps upload a picture to show what you want?

Comment: `\tabucline[1pt]{1-3}` and `|[1pt]` To change (add or remove) a vertical line one typically uses \multicolumn{1}...

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|l|X[c]|l|},
  hline{1,2} = {1pt},
  hline{3},
  vlines = {1}{1pt},
  vlines = {2}{},
}
  item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
  item 21 & item 22 & item 23 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cX[c]c}[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\Block[draw,line-width=1pt]{}{}}
  item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
  item 21 & item 22 & item 23 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]